# Docker and Youtrack over SSL

Tags: ssl, docker, youtrack

I'm testing youtrack and installed it using docker with the image uniplug/youtrack-docker. I am new to docker; I am having trouble setting it up to use SSL. Any suggestion on how I could accomplish this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The image you've selected won't support this, [it only listens on port 80](https://github.com/uniplug/youtrack-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile#L22)

you have a couple of options:

You can add a reverse proxy. There's an example of running a reverse proxy on the host in the [git readme](https://github.com/uniplug/youtrack-docker#service-example-with-jwildernginx-proxy) - you could also run a second container and [network them](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/), with the reverse proxy running in another container.

Your other option is to create your own Dockerfile. So for example, you could create a Dockerfile with the following:

```
FROM uniplug/youtrack-docker

EXPOSE 443/tcp

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord","-n","-c","/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]
```

Then you'd need to mount your SSL config using [additional settings options](https://github.com/uniplug/youtrack-docker#additional-settings)